# Categorising numerical and categorical variables into appropriate ranges in R

Tags: r, variables, categorical-data

```
 Df <- bball5
 str(bball5)
 'data.frame':  379 obs. of 9 variables:
 $ ID         : int  238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 ...
 $ Sex        : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sport      : Factor w/ 10 levels "BBall","Field",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 $ Ht         : num  196 190 178 185 185 ...
 $ Wt         : num  78.9 74.4 69.1 74.9 64.6 63.7 75.2 62.3 66.5 62.9 ...
 $ BMI        : num  20.6 20.7 21.9 21.9 19 ...
 $ BMIc       : NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sex_f      : Factor w/ 1 level "female": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sex_m      : Factor w/ 1 level "male": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

I would like to class a set of numerical variables within a large dataset of a 1000.

I need to classify BMI into the following ranges:

```
    (<18.50, 18.50-24.99, 24.99-25.00, >=30.00)
```

and label them respectively as:

```
  "Underweight" "Normal" "Overweight" "Obese"
```

So as to plot tables to demonstrate relationships that are the separate for:
     $ males
     $ females
according to sport types.

I also need to confirm that the BMI calculated is correctly done, as I am finding it difficult to create formula within the dataset for a new variable column

```
$ BMIc.
```

There are several missing values in variables (NA),within each variable, which are giving me errors if I create a function to calculate the a new variable

```
 bball5$BMIc <- bball5$BMI[bball5$BMI, c(bball5$wt/(bball5$Ht)^2 ]
```

I am unable to class the BMI variables.
I must maintain the ID to match as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable named `BMIclass` and do this to create the 4 categories in it:

```
bball5$BMIclass <- "Underweight"
bball5[which(bball5$BMI>18.5 & ball5$BMI<24.99), 'BMIclass'] <- "Normal"
bball5[which(bball5$BMI>=24.99 & ball5$BMI<25), 'BMIclass'] <- "Overweight"
bball5[which(bball5$BMI>=30), 'BMIclass'] <- "Obese"
bball5$BMIclass <- as.factor(bball5$BMIc)
```

As for `BMIc` you can do this (below). It will still create some NAs where there are missing values but it will give you the correct BMIc where there is data for it.

```
bball5$BMIc <- bball5$wt/bball5$Ht^2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `cut` to transform BMI into a categorical variable. An example on a random BMI vector:

```
BMI <- runif(100, 16, 35)
BMIc <- cut(BMI, breaks=c(0, 18.5, 25, 30, +Inf), 
            labels=c("Underweight", "Normal", "Overweight", "Obese"))
```

To check the result, you could use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(BMI, by=list(BMIc), summary)
```

Finally, the new vector can be included in the data frame with the command `df$BMIc <- BMIc` for example...

Comment: Thank you so much !  That has been really helpful been really helpful.